# How to Concatenate Same Node Values With XQuery

Tags: sql-server, xml, concatenation

I'm trying to insert XML to a Table with XQuery. Some nodes are multiple, but there's only one column in the Table, so I need to concatenate same nodes.

How can I iterate in a `"INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM @xmlDoc.nodes ..."` kind of query.

Here's a sample of my xml file

```
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>aaa</FirstName>
        <LastName>bbb</LastName>
        <DocumentNumber>AA 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>BB 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <WorkPlace>AAA Ltd</WorkPlace>
        <WorkPlace>BBB Ltd</WorkPlace>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>ccc</FirstName>
        <LastName>ddd</LastName>
        <DocumentNumber>CCC 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>DDD 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>EEE 1234</DocumentNumber>     
        <WorkPlace>CCC Ltd</WorkPlace>
        <WorkPlace>DDD Ltd</WorkPlace>
    </Person>
</Persons>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Standard complain XQuery engines have implemented [`string-join()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) XPath 2.0 function. But SQL-Server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version using a cte to isolate DocumentNumber and WorkPlace in xml columns first and then using for xml path('') to concatenate the values.

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml =
'
<Persons>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>aaa</FirstName>
        <LastName>bbb</LastName>
        <DocumentNumber>AA 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>BB 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <WorkPlace>AAA Ltd</WorkPlace>
        <WorkPlace>BBB Ltd</WorkPlace>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>ccc</FirstName>
        <LastName>ddd</LastName>
        <DocumentNumber>CCC 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>DDD 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>EEE 1234</DocumentNumber>     
        <WorkPlace>CCC Ltd</WorkPlace>
        <WorkPlace>DDD Ltd</WorkPlace>
    </Person>
</Persons>
'

;with cte as
(
  select
    p.value('FirstName[1]', 'varchar(50)') as FirstName,
    p.value('LastName[1]', 'varchar(50)') as LastName,
    p.query('DocumentNumber') as docXML,
    p.query('WorkPlace') as workXML
  from
    @xml.nodes('Persons/Person') p(p)
)
select
  FirstName,
  LastName,
  (select d.value('.', 'varchar(100)')+' '
   from cte.docXML.nodes('DocumentNumber') d(d)
   for xml path('')) as DocumentNumber,
  (select w.value('.', 'varchar(100)')+' '
   from cte.workXML.nodes('WorkPlace') w(w)
   for xml path('')) as WorkPlace
from cte
```

Comment: It works perfect, but can I you, please, explain me, how does it concatenates nodes? I can't figure it out.

Comment: It is a combination of using `for xml path('')` and a calculated column `d.value('.', 'varchar(100)')+' '` with no column name. This will give you a xml output with no root node and no name for the column nodes. Left is only the concatenated string.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is very poorly organized..... the trouble is the multiple entries of `<DocumentNumber>` and `<WorkPlace>` entities directly inside `<Person>` and not within their own "container" node.

This makes is extremely hard to get this parsed properly.....

If you want to grab only the names, you could use this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<Persons>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>aaa</FirstName>
        <LastName>bbb</LastName>
        <DocumentNumber>AA 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>BB 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <WorkPlace>AAA Ltd</WorkPlace>
        <WorkPlace>BBB Ltd</WorkPlace>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <FirstName>ccc</FirstName>
        <LastName>ddd</LastName>
        <DocumentNumber>CCC 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>DDD 1234</DocumentNumber>
        <DocumentNumber>EEE 1234</DocumentNumber>     
        <WorkPlace>CCC Ltd</WorkPlace>
        <WorkPlace>DDD Ltd</WorkPlace>
    </Person>
</Persons>'

SELECT
    Person.value('(FirstName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'First Name',
    Person.value('(LastName)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 'Last Name'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/Persons/Person') AS Persons(Person)
```

and of course, you could also do an `INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(FirstName, LastName)` before that select to store the information.

But again: trying to get those `<DocumentNumber>` and `<WorkPlace>` nodes into a proper format is really really hard..... you either end up duplicating data, or you have to do a second and third parsing pass to get this stuff properly stored.

Comment: There's nothing I can do with XML file, it's an external source, that I need to import to a table. What can I do in this situation to insert multiple documentNumbers, if I don't know even count of same nodes? Solution, you've described I'm using now, but I need to have some kind of dynamic iterate thing to concat all documentNumber values and insert into one column?